Migrate Flutter Sqlite to Kotlin Room
I have a production app made with Flutter that I started as a side project, now it has couple hundred users and I want to migrate the codebase to Kotlin (yes Im going to rewrite all the code).
The problem I'm facing is with the database, I currently use Sqlite in Flutter and I want to use Room without losing any of the user data.
Is this posible? If not, can I still use the same Sqlite after the user update the new version of the app made with Kotlin?

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/sqlite-room-migration

You can retain all your data with no issues.
Put your database file .db to the assets folder
and build the database like this:
    Room.databaseBuilder(context,YourDb::class.java,"YourDBName")
.createFromAsset("assets/YourDBName.db")
.build()

make sure that your model classes representing the entities match the columns and datatypes of your database file

That´s an interesting approach. But how can I move the database to the res folder on the users devices?

@OmarMartinez you cannot unless you have access to the devices and root access at that (I believe).


I currently use Sqlite in Flutter and I want to use Room without losing any of the user data. Is this posible?

Yes (albeit potentially complex, see supplementary demo that covers some complexities).
Assuming that each existing user(device) has data unique to that user then you  can effectively utilise that existing data.
Basically you need to change the App to introduce @Entity annotated classes, one per existing table.

Each will have fields, which equate to columns as per the existing database. - The class names can either be as per the existing table names or you can utilise the tableName parameter of the @Entity annotation to specify the table name to be utilised.

You should then create the @Database annotated class with the list of @Entity annotated classes provided via the entities parameter of the @Database annotation.
At this stage you should successfully compile the project. The java(generated) directory would then include a subdirectory with a class that is the same name as the @Database annotated class but suffixed with _Impl.
Within this class there will be a function/method called createAllTables. This will have an execSQL statement for creating each table (you can ignore the room_master table), and if any, a statement for the creation of indexes.
This SQL is exactly the schema that Room EXPECTS. Room will not accept any difference.
If the definition exactly matches the existing tables then in theory you could continue as such (database version number being the same). However, if there are any differences then you would need to convert(migrate) the tables.
Migration from non-room compliant tables to room-compliant tables could be reached by following the following steps (assuming the number of columns per table remain unchanged)
In the migration/conversion code per table:-

rename the original table using the ALTER TABLE the_table RENAME TO the_table_renamed;

the identifiers here are just descriptive
the _renamed part could be whatever suits but it is probably best to be consistent.


Using the SQL as copied from the generated java create the replacement table.
Use an INSERT .... SELECT to copy the data from the renamed original table into the newly created replacement table.

In it's simplest form INSERT INTO the_table SELECT * FROM the_table_renamed;.
Note that you may well have to use a more complex form explicitly naming the columns, e.g.:-
1.if the columns are not defined in the same order, or if you need to convert data

you had a column or columns that did not originally have  a NOT NULL constraint but have the NOT NULL constraint, then you may need to convert the null into a non-null value (perhaps using the SQLite coalesce function)




Optionally DROP the renamed original table e.g. DROP TABLE IF EXISTS the_table_renamed;
If indexes are to be created then for each index:-

Drop the index e.g. DROP INDEX IF EXISTS the_index;
Create the INDEX using the SQL as copied from the generated java



You may want to test that the above works before proceeding.
You would very likely have to convert all the functions that access the database INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs and QUERYs. Using either the equivalent convenience methods @Insert, @Update and @Delete. Noting:-

the @Update and @Delete convenience methods on the @PrimaryKey (required for all Room tables) to identify the row that is to be affected, the methods have the advantage of return an Int the value being the number of affected rows.
the @Insert convenience method returns the rowid of the inserted row (not necessarily the PrimaryKey value)
You can use an @Query("the_respective_sql") to get around the shortfalls of the convenience methods. e.g. it is impossible to use the convenience @Update to change the value of the primary key, but this could be done utilising e.g. @Query("UPDATE the_table SET pkey=:newPkey WHERE pkey=:oldPkey")

it should be noted that such uses do not return values like the convenience methods do.



In regard to Queries and Relationships you typically utilise a POJO (class not annotated with @Entity) where a field for the parent is annotated with @Embedded and the child(ren) field (typically a List<the_respective_@entity_annotated_child_class>) annotated with @Relation annotation.

Thank you for the detailed answer, one question, this "Basically you need to change the App to introduce @Entity annotated classes, one per existing table." will be in the new Kotlin codebase or I have to do it as a prerequisite in Flutter?

@OmarMartinez not sure about flutter supporting Room, if Flutter does then it could be in Flutter but probably best in Kotlin. Will probably update (or add additionbal) answer to show an example conversion (but all in Kotlin as I don't use Flutter).

@OmarMartinez supplementary answer (demo) added.

Demo Note using Kotlin (never used Flutter but principles should apply)
First consider the non-Room database:-
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
const val TABLEA_NAME = "table_a"
const val TABLEB_NAME = "table_b"
const val TABLEA_COL_COL1 = "c1"
const val TABLEA_COL_COL2 = "c2"
const val TABLEA_COL_COL3 = "c3"
const val TABLEB_COL_COL1 = "c1"
const val TABLEB_COL_COL2 = "c2"
const val TABLEB_COL_COL3 = "c3"
const val TABLEA_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLEA_NAME} (${TABLEA_COL_COL1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ${TABLEA_COL_COL2} WIERD_COLUMN_TYPE, ${TABLEA_COL_COL3} REAL);"
const val TABLEB_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLEB_NAME} (${TABLEB_COL_COL1} TEXT PRIMARY KEY, ${TABLEB_COL_COL2} NUMERIC, ${TABLEB_COL_COL3} BLOB)"

class DBHelper(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db!!.execSQL(TABLEA_CRTSQL)
        db!!.execSQL(TABLEB_CRTSQL)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    fun insertIntoA(c1: Long?=null,c2: String,c3: Double): Long {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        if (c1!=null) {
            cv.put(TABLEA_COL_COL1,c1)
        }
        cv.put(TABLEA_COL_COL2,c2)
        cv.put(TABLEA_COL_COL3,c3)
        return this.writableDatabase.insert(TABLEA_NAME,null,cv)
    }
    fun insertIntoB(c1: String,c2: String,c3: ByteArray): Long {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        if (c1!=null) {
            cv.put(TABLEB_COL_COL1,c1)
        }
        cv.put(TABLEB_COL_COL2,c2)
        cv.put(TABLEB_COL_COL3,c3)
        return this.writableDatabase.insert(TABLEB_NAME,null,cv)
    }

    fun showAll() {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Starting Extract of all data from tables ${TABLEA_NAME} and ${TABLEB_NAME}.")
        var csr = this.writableDatabase.query(TABLEA_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr = this.writableDatabase.query(TABLEB_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr.close()
        Log.d("DBINFO","Completed Extract of all data from tables ${TABLEA_NAME} and ${TABLEB_NAME}.")
    }

}


i.e. uses the SQLiteDatabase via SQLiteOpenHelper (typicall non-room approach)

i.e. 2 tables:-

CREATE TABLE table_a (c1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, c2 WIERD_COLUMN_TYPE, c3 REAL)
CREATE TABLE table_b (c1 TEXT PRIMARY KEY, c2 NUMERIC, c3 BLOB)





To convert first the two @Entity annotated classes (1 for each table):-
/*
    Based upon const val TABLEA_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLEA_NAME} (${TABLEA_COL_COL1} INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ${TABLEA_COL_COL2} WIERD_COLUMN_TYPE, ${TABLEA_COL_COL3} REAL);"
 */
@Entity(tableName = TABLEA_NAME)
data class TableA(
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(TABLEA_COL_COL1) /* use THIS column name even though field name (id) is different */
    val id: Long?=null, /* note even though nullable, null will result in generated id */
    @ColumnInfo(name = TABLEA_COL_COL2)
    val col2: String, /* Best fit for weird type?????? */
    val c3: Double /* Here field has same name as the original column name so no need to name the column */
)
/*
    Based up const val TABLEB_CRTSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${TABLEB_NAME} (${TABLEB_COL_COL1} TEXT PRIMARY KEY, ${TABLEB_COL_COL2} NUMERIC, ${TABLEB_COL_COL3} BLOB)"
 */
@Entity /* as the class name matches the original table name no need for tableName parameter */
data class Table_B(
    @PrimaryKey val c1: String,
    val c2: Double, /* NUMERIC could be anything so assumed Double is a fit????? BUT purposefully originally had strings*/
    val c3: ByteArray /* BLOB equates to Byte Array */
)


see the comments

It should be noted that some factors have been introduced to make the conversion more complex (some columns have had an implicit NOT NULL constraint added e.g. instead of val c2: Double? val c2:Double has been used, thus c2 cannot be null and Room EXPECTS (demands) this).
A little over complex, as explained, then consider the following conversion function:-
    private fun checkForAndDoConversion(context: Context) {
        val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path,null,0)
        val csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,"name='room_master_table'",null,null,null,null)
        var alreadyRoomDB = false
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            alreadyRoomDB=true
            Log.d("DBINFO","No need for conversion as room_master_table does exist.")
        } else {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Conversion required as room_master_table does not exist.")
        }
        csr.close()
        if (alreadyRoomDB) return
        Log.d("DBINFO","Converting database")
        val original_suffix = "_renamed"
        /* STEP1 Rename the tables to be converted */
        showSchema(db,"BEFORE CONVERSION")
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${TABLEA_NAME}${original_suffix}")
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${TABLEB_NAME}${original_suffix}")
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ${TABLEA_NAME} RENAME TO ${TABLEA_NAME}${original_suffix};")
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ${TABLEB_NAME} RENAME TO ${TABLEB_NAME}${original_suffix};")
        /* STEP 2 create the replacement/converted tables with >>>>>>>>>>SQL copied from TheDatabase_Impl in java(generated)<<<<<<<<<< */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_a` (`c1` INTEGER, `c2` TEXT NOT NULL, `c3` REAL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`c1`));")
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Table_B` (`c1` TEXT NOT NULL, `c2` REAL NOT NULL, `c3` BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`c1`))")
        showSchema(db,"AFTER RENAMES AND CREATES")
        /* Extract and Load data from renamed original table into the new replacement table for TABLEA*/
        db.execSQL(
            "INSERT INTO ${TABLEA_NAME} " +
                    "(" +
                    "${TABLEA_COL_COL1}" +
                    ",${TABLEA_COL_COL2}" +
                    ",${TABLEB_COL_COL3}" +
                    ") " +
                    "SELECT " +
                    "${TABLEA_COL_COL1}" +
                    ",coalesce(${TABLEA_COL_COL2},'WAS NULL') " + /* just in case c2 has a null value */
                    ",coalesce(${TABLEA_COL_COL3},9999.9999)" + /* just in case c3 has a null value */
                    " FROM ${TABLEA_NAME}${original_suffix}" +
                    ";"
        )
        db.execSQL(
            "INSERT INTO ${TABLEB_NAME} " +
                    "(" +
                    "${TABLEB_COL_COL1}" +
                    ",${TABLEB_COL_COL2}" +
                    ",${TABLEB_COL_COL3}" +
                    ") " +
                    "SELECT " +
                    "coalesce(${TABLEB_COL_COL1},'OOOPS'||rowid)" +
                    ",coalesce(${TABLEB_COL_COL2},9999.9999)" +
                    ",coalesce(${TABLEB_COL_COL3},zeroblob(4))" +
                    " FROM ${TABLEB_NAME}${original_suffix}" +
                    ";"
        )
        /* Drop the renamed tables */
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${TABLEA_NAME}${original_suffix};")
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ${TABLEB_NAME}${original_suffix};")
    }


this being the crux and is as per (at least closely) previous answer which this answer supplements.
Especially note the 2 CREATE TABLE's. the SQL has been copied directly from the java(generated) for the TheDatabase_Impl class (so you know that the Room @Database annotated class is TheDatabase):-


this is why creation of the @Entity annotated classes, based upon the existing database is suggested as the first step.



The showSchema function, used for debugging (if necessary), it is simply:-
    private fun showSchema(db: SQLiteDatabase, stage: String) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Start of Showing Schema for Stage ${stage}")
        val csr = db.query("sqlite_master",null,null,null,null,null,null)
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr.close()
        Log.d("DBINFO","Completed Showing Schema for Stage ${stage}")
    }

Both of these functions are static functions (java speak) aka within a companion object in Kotlin. They are in the @Database annotated TheDatabase abstract class which is:-
@Database(entities = [TableA::class,Table_B::class], exportSchema = false, version = DATABASE_VERSION)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDAOs(): AllDAOs
    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            checkForAndDoConversion(context)
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity of the demo */
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
        private fun checkForAndDoConversion(context: Context) {
            .... (see above for the function)
        }
        private fun showSchema(db: SQLiteDatabase, stage: String) {
            .... (see above for the function)
        }
    }
}


it should be noted that for brevity of the demo the main thread is used hence the allowMainThreadQueries()

As can be see the abstract function getAllDAOs() returns an AllDAOs this being:-
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(tableA: TableA): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(tableB: Table_B): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${TABLEA_NAME}")
    fun getAllFromTableA(): List<TableA>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${TABLEB_NAME}")
    fun getAllFromTableB(): List<Table_B>
    @Transaction
    @Query("")
    fun showAllEquivalent() {
        val sb = StringBuilder().append("TableA contains:-")
        for (a in getAllFromTableA()) {
            sb.append("\n\t${TABLEA_COL_COL1}=${a.id} ${TABLEA_COL_COL2}=${a.col2} ${TABLEA_COL_COL3}=${a.c3}")
        }
        sb.append("\nTableB contains:-")
        for (b in getAllFromTableB()) {
            sb.append("\n\t${TABLEB_COL_COL1}=${b.c1} ${TABLEB_COL_COL2}=${b.c2} ${TABLEB_COL_COL3}=${b.c3}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Result of showAllEquivalent is:-${sb}")
    }
}


hopefully these should be virtually self explanatory, except perhaps the showALlEquivalent the dummy @Query("") allows the @Transaction to actually be considered, so the body of the function is run within a single transaction.

The remaining code is activity code. In this demo the original database is created and populated and then converted and used by Room, as per:-
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dboriginal: DBHelper
    lateinit var roomdb: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        /* do the original (pre-room) DB */
        dboriginal = DBHelper(this)
        doOriginal(dboriginal)
        dboriginal.close()

        /* Now the Room version conversion */
        roomdb = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = roomdb.getAllDAOs()
        dao.showAllEquivalent()
    }


    fun doOriginal(db: DBHelper) {
        for(i: Int in 1..10) {
            if (i % 2 > 0) {
                db.insertIntoA(c1=(i*10).toLong(), c2="Row ${i}", c3= (i * 100).toDouble() / 3.213)
            } else {
                db.insertIntoA(c2="Row ${i}",c3=(i*300).toDouble())
            }
            db.insertIntoB(c1="Row${i}", c2="${i} was the base for this row.",c3 = ByteArray(i*10))
        }
        db.insertIntoA(c2="FirstRow",c3=111.1234)
        db.insertIntoB("ThisRowisTheFirst","Some more data",ByteArray(10))
        db.showAll()
    }
}

The doOriginal adds 10 rows to each table, and then extracts them and dumps them to the log e.g. :-
2024-05-09 13:33:19.463 D/DBINFO: Starting Extract of all data from tables table_a and table_b.
2024-05-09 13:33:19.463 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@aa6612
2024-05-09 13:33:19.464 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.464 I/System.out:    c1=10
2024-05-09 13:33:19.464 I/System.out:    c2=Row 1
2024-05-09 13:33:19.464 I/System.out:    c3=31.1236
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out: }
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out:    c1=11
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out:    c2=Row 2
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out:    c3=600
2024-05-09 13:33:19.465 I/System.out: }
....
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out: 10 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out:    c1=92
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out:    c2=FirstRow
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out:    c3=111.123
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out: }
2024-05-09 13:33:19.468 I/System.out: <<<<<


2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@79321e3
2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out:    c1=Row1
2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out:    c2=1 was the base for this row.
2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out:    c3=<unprintable>
2024-05-09 13:33:19.469 I/System.out: }
2024-05-09 13:33:19.470 I/System.out: 1 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.470 I/System.out:    c1=Row2
2024-05-09 13:33:19.470 I/System.out:    c2=2 was the base for this row.
2024-05-09 13:33:19.470 I/System.out:    c3=<unprintable>
2024-05-09 13:33:19.470 I/System.out: }
....
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out: 10 {
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out:    c1=ThisRowisTheFirst
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out:    c2=Some more data
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out:    c3=<unprintable>
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out: }
2024-05-09 13:33:19.473 I/System.out: <<<<<


i.e. the data before the conversion to Room

When the code roomdb = TheDatabase.getInstance(this) is executed then that is when the conversion is undertaken

but NOT the opening of the database by Room, that is not undertaken until an attempt is made to access the database (similar to SQLiteOpenHelper).

That is checkForAndDoConversion(context)   is executed. This does a rudimentary check to see if the database has been taken over by room (i.e. to see if room_master_table exists, this table holds a hash of the schema as room expects, used for testing to see if changes have been made to the schema). As the table should not exist in the demo then the conversion is undertaken.
Finally the showAllEquivalent function (extract via Room) is invoked:-
2024-05-09 13:48:58.921 D/DBINFO: Result of showAllEquivalent is:-TableA contains:-
        c1=10 c2=Row 1 c3=31.12356053532524
        c1=11 c2=Row 2 c3=600.0
        c1=30 c2=Row 3 c3=93.37068160597572
        c1=31 c2=Row 4 c3=1200.0
        c1=50 c2=Row 5 c3=155.6178026766262
        c1=51 c2=Row 6 c3=1800.0
        c1=70 c2=Row 7 c3=217.8649237472767
        c1=71 c2=Row 8 c3=2400.0
        c1=90 c2=Row 9 c3=280.11204481792714
        c1=91 c2=Row 10 c3=3000.0
        c1=92 c2=FirstRow c3=111.1234
    TableB contains:-
        c1=Row1 c2=1.0 c3=[B@303ae36
        c1=Row2 c2=2.0 c3=[B@b69d137
        c1=Row3 c2=3.0 c3=[B@15706a4
        c1=Row4 c2=4.0 c3=[B@cebfc0d
        c1=Row5 c2=5.0 c3=[B@65477c2
        c1=Row6 c2=6.0 c3=[B@8049d3
        c1=Row7 c2=7.0 c3=[B@94fe910
        c1=Row8 c2=8.0 c3=[B@2694c09
        c1=Row9 c2=9.0 c3=[B@3f64e0e
        c1=Row10 c2=10.0 c3=[B@87bb02f
        c1=ThisRowisTheFirst c2=0.0 c3=[B@fb2863c


The data does not exactly match:-

TableB c2 was text and due to SQLite's TYPE flexibility remained as text BUT room has duly extracted a double value (note the CUATION)
TableB  c3* is the address/pointer to the BLOB (ByteArray) as opposes to <unprintable> (blob handling is often an issue). However, Room has handled the extraction.



Using App inspection shows:-

and:-


as can be seen App Inspection handles the blobs (at least at the sizes used)

Additional
in the above TableB column c2 remained as TEXT and was not converted to a REAL. This could perhaps be handled by a more complex column conversion such as:-
",coalesce(CASE typeOf(${TABLEB_COL_COL2})WHEN 'REAL' THEN ${TABLEB_COL_COL2} ELSE null END,9999.9999)" +


i.e. if the type of data held (on a per row basis) is not REAL then it is replaced by NULL but then converted, by the coalesce function to 9999.9999.

Using this conversion then results in showAllEquivalent displaying:-
TableB contains:-
    c1=Row1 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@303ae36
    c1=Row2 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@b69d137
    c1=Row3 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@15706a4
    c1=Row4 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@cebfc0d
    c1=Row5 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@65477c2
    c1=Row6 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@8049d3
    c1=Row7 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@94fe910
    c1=Row8 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@2694c09
    c1=Row9 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@3f64e0e
    c1=Row10 c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@87bb02f
    c1=ThisRowisTheFirst c2=9999.9999 c3=[B@fb2863c

and App Inspection showing:-

